# Haskell IO with interact and map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, io, buffering

I am trying to produce an interactive Haskell program using the `interact` function with `map`.

Here's what I get in **ghci** (as far as I can tell, that's the way all tutorials explain `interact` usage -- except the result).

```
*Module> interact $ unlines . map (++ "!") . lines
tteesstt
!
```

Note that what actually happens is that every character I type is instantly repeated and after I press Return the exclamation mark appears. I was, however, expecting this:

```
*Module> interact $ unlines . map (++ "!") . lines
test
test!
```

It works perfectly if I use the same program structure, but `filter` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that ghci changes the buffering mode to per-character. This is, that the program starts to process the code as soon as it is there. If you write this line into a file called `foo.hs`

```
main = interact $ unlines . map (++ "!") . lines
```

and run it using `runhaskell foo.hs` you will see that it works as expected, because Haskell uses line-buffering by default.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfectly correct. It is possible to set it to line buffering by executing `import IO` and then `hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering`.

Answer (score 3):

As FUZxxl says, [it's a buffering issue](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ghci-faq.html).

To change buffering styles in GHCi, use `hSetBuffering`

```
Prelude> :m +System.IO
Prelude System.IO> hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering 
Prelude System.IO> interact $ unlines . map (++"!") . lines
hello
hello!
^CInterrupted.
Prelude System.IO>
```